# dynamic setting variable in grid for tk widget

Tags: dynamic, tcl, tk-toolkit

Hi I want to make my widget dynamic.
suppose I have chunk like this :

```
grid [ttk::entry .c.directory_Pattern -width 20 -textvariable directory_Pattern] -column 2 -row 1 -sticky we
```

I want to create "n" number of boxes using for loop and to test it, i just tried instead of "-column 2" i want it to make dynamic like "-column $i"

Is this possible? I am getting error...How could i resolve the issue as i already set the value of "i" as 2?

Comment: apology it is wrking fine... i did the mistake

Comment: Feel free to delete your question if it is of no further value.